# Java and Jabber/Smack

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I am trying to code a simple example using the latest version of Smack (3.2.1) to send and receive messages between two accounts.

```
Connection connection = new XMPPConnection("jabber.org");
connection.connect();
connection.login("username", "password");
```

But I can't even get past the login part.  When I run the above code I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" SASL authentication DIGEST-MD5 failed: invalid-authzid: 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:337)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:203)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:348)
at com.smack.TestSmack.main(TestSmack.java:19)
```

What is going on here?  I am sure my username and password work because I can log in using my IM client.

And can anyone point me to current working Smack examples?  This is very frustrating because the documentation and the library seem out of sync.

Thanks-

Comment: You should delete this question, as I just lost 1 minute because I needed to find out in a comment that you mistyped your password. :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a misstyped password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you check that you are not adding "@jabber.org" at the end of the username? if you do, it will not work.

Otherwise, if you do that already, you may want to try using

`SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);`

before

`connection.login("username", "password");`

Comment: No, I don't have @jabber.org at the end of the username.  I tried adding the SASLAuthentication line, and I got this error:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" SASL authentication PLAIN failed: invalid-authzid: 
 at     org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:337)
 at     org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:203)
 at     org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:348)
 at com.smack.TestSmack.main(TestSmack.java:20)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion though.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I found the problem.  Embarrassingly, I was mistyping my password.  This is super lame and I am sorry I wasted your time.  I will give you credit for the solution so this gets closed out.

Comment: lol, I thought about it :-) thanks for the vote!

Comment: Hi @Guillaume i haved added the line but still it is giving the same issue any idea why i am getting this ?